# WinBUGS Condition Autoregressive Model issue while updating

Tags: r, bayesian, poisson, winbugs, autoregressive-models

```
model 
{
    for (i in 1 : N) {
        # Likelihood
        O[i] ~ dpois(crash[i])
        log(crash[i]) <- alpha0 + beta0*cent[i]+  beta*pop[i]  + betaadj*popN[i ] +  b[i] + h[i]
        h[i] ~ dnorm(0, tau.h)
                }

b[1:N] ~ car.normal(adj[], weights[], num[], tau.b)
for(k in 1:sumNumNeigh){
            weights[k] <- 1
  }


alpha0 ~ dnorm(0, 0.000001)
beta0 ~ dnorm(0, 0.000001)
beta ~ dnorm(0, 0.000001)
betaadj ~ dnorm(0, 0.000001)
tau.h ~ dgamma(0.01, 0.01)
sigma.b <- sqrt(1 / tau.b)
tau.b ~ dgamma(0.01, 0.01)
sigma.h <- sqrt(1 / tau.h)

}
```

I have generated initials and tried updating, but I am facing issue undefined real result.

As i changed the prior to these

```
alpha0 ~ dnorm(0, 10000)
beta0 ~ dnorm(0, 10000)
beta ~ dnorm(0, 10000)
betaadj ~ dnorm(0, 10000)
```

I am getting a command called **GLM1** in the left bottom. Here also i generated the initials instead of providing it. Can someone help me with the problem, the data is big as it contains 1035 values in each list.

Comment: What happens if you specify initial values in the middle of the prior distributions?

Comment: @DaveArmstrong again undefined real results pops up, should i make any changes to prior distributions

Comment: I think to go much further, we would need some data that reproduce the result.